# Why does the standard provide two options to call a function?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    void Message()
    {
        std::cout<<"You are calling the function of class Base ";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void Message()
    {
        std::cout<<"You are calling the function of class Derived ";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived obj1;
    obj1.Base::Message();
    return 0;
}
```

These two lines of code:

```
Derived obj1;
obj1.Base::Message();
```

Call the class `Derived` which is derived from `Base`. The second line of code calls the `Base` class overridden function `Message`.

Why does the standard introduce `obj1.Base::Message()` when we can directly call the function `Message` with this code?

```
Base obj1;
obj1.Message();
```

Comment: When you learn about member variables you will see the difference. The difference between `Derived obj1` and `Base obj1` will be important

Comment: The goal isn't to call the function. It's to apply the function to an object. Sure, you can create an object of a different type and apply the function directly, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: `obj1.Base::Message()` is not something you would normally use. It is more of a tool that could be use if you really need to call the base version but I would consider it as a red flag.

Comment: What Peter Backer said was reasonable. Creating an instance of Base class is also fine. However, to create a instance, you have to allocate memory, execute constructor and something like that. Therefoer, creating an instance of Base class so as to call its function is not an elegant solution.

Comment: On the other hand, the instance of Derived already comprises Base::Message(). It's not necessary to create another instance of Base class to call such function.

Answer (score 0):

`Base::Message` is necessary if you want to call that function on an object of type `Derived`.  In the particular example you give, it's true that an alternate way of doing this is to use `static_cast<Base&>(derived).Message()`.  However, in the case that `Message` is a virtual function, this won't work--you would always get `Message` from the most derived class.

One place where this is often used is if you are overriding a virtual function, but want to call the base function from within the derived one.  For example:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Message()
    {
        std::cout<<"You are calling the function of class Base ";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void Message() override
    {
        Base::Message();
        std::cout<<"(and now for the Derived-only part of the message)";
    }
};
```